# Huge void between columns Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am working on a page that has a two column general layout. On the left goes the photo and some descriptors, and on the right is the title and a description. I can get the columns setup just fine, and everything fits. The problem is there is a huge white space that shows up in between the two columns. I am not sure exactly what is the best way to clean it up.

This is the iphone 4 view of the page (so .xs)

[image]

This is the 1080p version 
[image]

Bootstrap Code (using jade template engine)

```
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-body
                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                            .row
                                .col-xs-6.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        |</br></br>
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        img(src = '/images/stub photos/event stub 1.jpg', alt='Cinque Terre', width='150', height='150')
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        .event-item
                                            a(href='http://localhost:3000') Concerned Citizens for Rivers
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                                        .event-item
                                                | 12/31/15 11:50 AM - 12/31/15 11:50 AM
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        .event-item
                                                | 1234 Fake Street, Sacramento
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        .event-item
                                                | 100 attending of 200
                                .col-xs-6.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        h4 
                                            a(href='http://localhost:3000') American River Cleanup!
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        img(src = '/images/interests/environment.png', alt='Cinque Terre', width='30', height='30')
                                        img(src = '/images/interests/people.png', alt='Cinque Terre', width='30', height='30')
                                        img(src = '/images/interests/youth.png', alt='Cinque Terre', width='30', height='30')
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        |</br>
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        |center sodales malesuada accumsan vel, condimentum eget eros. Mauris consectetur nisi in ex pharetra commodo. Nullam aliquam velit sem, nec molestie risus eleifend ac. In fringilla, nisl ac gravida convallis, turpis eros accumsan urna, sed molestie tortor libero sit amet lacus. Nulla porttitor euismod purus, ut hendrerit leo vehicula sed. Aenean ad
                                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                        button.btn.btn-default(ng-click='') Sign-up

                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                            .row
                                .col-xs-6.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                                    .row
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            |</br></br>
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            img(src = '/images/stub photos/event stub 2.jpg', alt='Cinque Terre', width='150', height='150')
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            .event-item
                                                a(href='http://localhost:3000') Folsom Animal Center
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                                            .event-item
                                                    | 12/31/15 11:50 AM - 12/31/15 11:50 AM
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            .event-item
                                                    | 1234 Fake Street, Sacramento
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            .event-item
                                                    | 100 attending of 200
                                .col-xs-6.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6
                                    .row
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            h4 
                                                a(href='http://localhost:3000') Animal Shelter Needs Love
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            img(src = '/images/interests/animals.png', alt='Cinque Terre', width='30', height='30')
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            |</br>
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            |center sodales malesuada accumsan vel, condimentum eget eros. Mauris consectetur nisi in ex pharetra commodo. Nullam aliquam velit sem, nec molestie risus eleifend ac. In fringilla, nisl ac gravida convallis, turpis eros accumsan urna, sed molestie tortor libero sit amet lacus. Nulla porttitor euismod purus, ut hendrerit leo vehicula sed. Aenean ad
                                        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
                                            button.btn.btn-default(ng-click='') Sign-up
```

My css file

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}

body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


a {
    color: #00B7FF;
}



.center-item {
   display:block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.cursor-pointer {
   cursor: pointer;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.events-pane {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.event-description {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.float-right {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    right: 1%;
    top: 80px;
}

.event-item { 
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.float-btm {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    right: 50%;
}

.not-selected {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.selected {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(39, 62, 84, 0.82);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.subscriber-thumbnail {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

/**********************************************************************
    DIV CSS START
**********************************************************************/
.titleRow {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.calendarRow {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.upcomingEventsRow {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.organizersRow {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.subsribersRow {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.descriptionRow {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.organizersRow {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.volunteersRow {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.carousel-control {
  padding-top:10%;
  width:5%;
}
/**********************************************************************
    Event CSS END
**********************************************************************/
```

I hate to do a huge code dump on here, but I don't know what else to do. I have tried messing with the gutter sizes, but all of the examples I have found for how to do that don't seem to work, or seem to be written for sass or less, which I am not yet using. I would appreciate any advice or a point in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: one note, when you have `col-xs-12` there is no need to use `col-sm-12`

Comment: The column sizes look correct to me; the 1st and 3rd columns simply take-up less space.  Perhaps you could tell us what you would prefer to see?  Would you prefer that each column's data be centered within the column?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but you can put the content inside of another DIV and then use padding or margins to push the content toward the center.  You can use @media (max-width: xxx) in your CSS to change the margins/padding based on the width of the screen.